# Child template not being rendered in Django

Tags: python, django

[image]

In my django view I have:

```
def index(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html',context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

In my base template (index.html) I have:

```
 <div class="col-lg-5 col-sm-6">
                <hr class="section-heading-spacer" />
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <h2 class="section-heading">Here Are The Details:</h2>
                    {% block 'body' %}
                    {% endblock %}
            </div>
```

My 'ipsum.html' child template has:

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}
{% block 'body' %}
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
{% endblock %}
```

When I run it, The:

```
{% block 'body' %}
{% endblock %}
```

is gone, but nothing replaces it in index.html. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have a view that renders a response with `'ipsum.html'`? The only view I see renders `'index.html'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code you show above, it appears that you are not rendering a response with `'ipsum.html'`. Do you mean to do this instead (note the `'ipsum.html'`)?

```
def index(request):
    return render_to_response('ipsum.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Or do you perhaps need another view altogether?

```
def ipsum(request):
    return render_to_response('ipsum.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**EDIT**

With regard to your comment, you can extend templates with as many child templates as you'd like. For example, you might have the following three files:

**base.html**

```
<html>
  <body>
  {% block 'body' %}
    <p>testing 1</p>
  {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

**child1.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block 'body' %}
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
{% endblock %}
```

**THE DIRECT SECOND CHILD EXTENSION**

**child2.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block 'body' %}
<p>Quo usque tandem abutere, Catilina, patientia nostra?</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Since we have not added any new blocks to child2.html, the preferred method would be to inherit from `base.html`.

**ANOTHER POSSIBLE SECOND CHILD EXTENSION**

If, however, we add another block to `child1.html` like so (note `child1.html` now has **two** blocks):

**child1.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block 'body' %}
<p>Lorem ipsum . . .</p>
{% endblock %}
{% block second_p %}
<p>Another paragraph . . .</p>
{% endblock %}
```

We may want to extend the second child now, since we have a second block already built into that template that was not built into `base.html`:

**child2.html**

```
{% extends 'child1.html' %}
{% block 'body' %}
<p>Quo usque tandem abutere, Catilina, patientia nostra?</p>
{% endblock %}
{% block second_p %}
<p>And still another . . .</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Now your view can use any of these html files to render your template. Here are three views that render these three templates respectively:

```
def index(request):
    return render_to_response('base.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def child1(request):
    return render_to_response('child1.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def child2(request):
    return render_to_response('child2.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Thank you, you got it, but I have a question: Lets say I have a second child template. How do I trigger the integration of 2 separate child templates into a base template?

Comment: @user61629 Great! Glad you got it figured out. Your second child template can extend either the base template or your first child template in the same way you extend the first child template above. Just be sure to render the correct html file when you render the template. I'll see if I can add an example above.

Comment: @user61629 I updated my answer above. Did I understand your question correctly? You might do well to think of the base template being integrated into the child templates rather than the other way around.

Comment: Justin, thank you for your extremely detailed answer. I'm going to add this as a follow up question because I'm still confused.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27351864/integrating-and-rendering-2-child-templates-into-a-base-template-django

Comment: @user61629 Perfect. I checked out that question, and I think [biobirdman](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27352555/1775603) has mostly the right idea. You could also use [`include`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#include), but I think biobirdman's solution will be easier for you to implement. Let me know if you are still having trouble making sense of this. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have to say that I find this counter intuitive compared to php where you render the main template and pass in sub views - Bill