# Integrating and rendering 2 child templates into a base template - Django

Tags: python, html, django

[image]

I have a base template (index.html) and 2 child templates ipsum and need. I'm using blocks to try to integrate the 2 children into the base.

**base.html**

```
<html>
  <body>
  {% block 'body1' %}
    <p>testing 1</p>
  {% endblock %}
  {% block 'body2' %}
    <p>testing 2</p>
  {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

**child1.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block 'body1' %}
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
{% endblock %}
```

**child2.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block 'body2' %}
<p>Quo usque tandem abutere, Catilina, patientia nostra?</p>
{% endblock %}
```

If there was only 1 block, I now understand that I could call in my view:

```
def index(request):
    return render_to_response('ipsum.html',context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

What could I do to fill both blocks in index.html - 1 with ipsum.html and the other with need.html?

Comment: are there 4 templates? child1.html child2.html ipsum and need.

Comment: @user61629 please do look at my answer, it is correct. Thank you. And do accept my answer. I need it for my job . Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should ask the first child to extend the 2nd child which will extend base html. This is how you extend multiple child templates in django.

Hence your code should look like this:

#### index.html

```
<html>
<body>
  {% block 'body1' %}
  {% endblock %}
  {% block 'body2' %}
  {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

#### ipsum.html

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}
{% block 'body1' %}
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
{% endblock %}
```

#### need.html

```
{% extends 'ipsum.html' %}
{% block 'body2' %}
    <p>Quo usque tandem abutere, Catsdsilina, patientia nostra?</p>
{% endblock %}
```

#### views.py

```
def index(request):
    return render_to_response('need.html',context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

so need `need.html` will first be rendered, it will look for `ipsum.html` and when `ipsum.html` is rendered, it will look for `index.html`

### Alternatively

If you will like to do inclusion instead of extension, I recommend using the Django Sekizai library http://django-sekizai.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ . It includes custom tags such as `{% include 'xx.html' %}` that will render the 2nd child template in your first child if needed.

Cheers,
BioBirdMan

Here is a working example:

http://biobirdman.com/stacktest/nestedtemplate/

Comment: Thank you very much. I have to say that I find this counterintuitive compared to php where you render the main template and pass in sub views - Bill

Comment: Inheritance from base is great for site design but don't forget there is not only 'extend' but also 'include' for passing templates into other templates

Comment: @user61629 aka bill. Do take a look at my updated answer on an external library call seikzai, which is compliment really well with the default django templating mechanism and is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this would be to only have one block in the base template, and override that block in each child template, like:

base.html:

```
<html>
  <body>

      {% block 'content' %} gets overridden {% endblock %}

  </body>
</html>
```

child1.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block 'content' %}

    <h1> Page 1 </h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>

{% endblock %}
```

child2.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block 'content' %}

    <h1> Page 2 </h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>

{% endblock %}
```